# Rewrite URL but keep external files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been making a web app with PHP but the problem is that when I try to rewrite:

> http://example.com/user.php?username=user121

to:

> http://example.com/user/user121

with HTACCESS, it loses all external files and only keeps the page's HTML. Please help me out?

My current Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule users/([^/]+) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **any one** of these solutions.

**Solution 1:**  use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Solution 2:** Try adding this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

**Solution 3:** Add this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule users/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: All solutions work but solution 3 works without the R=301 flag. Thanks